# Reading .txt file columns into pandas data frame and creating new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .txt file which looks like the following:

```
      156 2.87893e+06
      157 968759
      699 2.15891e+06
      700 44927.2
      1108 830338
      1156 70513.5
      1172 64263.2
```

The above file is an output file I am obtaining on running a c++ prog. I want this output file in pandas df.

I tried following code:

```
       df = pd.read_csv("output.txt", index_col=0)
       df
```

But here, columns from .txt file becomes one column in the df. I want the values in 2 columns separately, maybe with a column heading.

OR since its a text file, if they are not 2 different columns in .txt file, then each row has 2 values separated by a space. How can I get them in two different cols in pandas df ?

Also, I tried the following code:

```
        df = pd.read_csv("output.txt")
        df.iloc[:,(0)]
```

Now, here the very first row from the original text file doesn't appears at all, and again both the values appear in one column.

Comment: Have you tried sep= ' ' as an argument to read_csv()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default delimiter for `pandas.read_csv` is comma `,`, you need to explicitly specify the `sep` parameter to be space in order to read in space delimited file:

```
df = pd.read_csv("output.txt", sep = " ", index_col=0, header=None)
```

Comment: On implementing what you suggested, it considers the first row of data as column names.

Comment: Use header=None, if the file doesn't contain column names.